# 2 programs in different directories with the same name: what happens when I type that name?

Tags: linux, directory, command

I am a beginner in this field, and this is a question from a quiz we were handed in class. Could you guys help please?

Question: "Two programs, in different directories, have the same name. One is a system program. The other is a script that you wrote. What happens when you type that name?"

Comment: To answer that you first need on answer: "How does the shell, know where to find programs?"

Answer (score 5):

If neither is on your search path, then you get "command not found"

If only one is on your search path, it gets run.

If both are on your search path, the one that comes earlier in the search path is run.

Being a system program makes no difference.

If the first script or program found by path and name is not executable, it fails to run: Permission denied. It does not search the rest of the paths for a version it can run.

Comment: The full story is in "GNU Bash Reference Manual"  section "Command Search and Execution". Not bedtime reading, but worth bookmarking. I keep it open 24/7, along with "The GNU Awk User’s Guide".

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Being a shell-built-in (shell-built-in is not identical to system program) will make a difference.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor "In different directories" indicates they are not built-ins. Good point though, as regards built-ins, aliases, and sourced functions. I wasted 10 minutes checking that it would stop searching at a non-executable by creating ~/bin/ls, before I found my own ls is an alias. Not to mention the joys of calling your first script "test" and then trying to get it to run.

Comment: Two great commands to identify why the shell is not going to run `myCmd` when you want it to. `type myCmd` tells you what kind of executable beast it is. `which myCmd` tells you where the PATH led it to, assuming it is a real file.